# How to populate relations with the QueryBuilder

Tags: typeorm

I have this model:

```
@Entity()
export class Trade extends BaseEntity {
    ...
    @OneToOne(() => Fee, { cascade: true })
    @JoinColumn()
    fee: Fee;
    ...
}


@Entity()
export class Fee extends BaseEntity {
    ...
    @OneToOne(() => Trade, trade => trade.fee)
    trade!: Trade
    ...
}
```

I'm trying to get the equivalent of:

```
await getManager().find(Trade, { relations: ['fee'] })
```

with the QueryBuilder.

```
await createQueryBuilder('trade')
    .leftJoinAndSelect(Fee, 'fee', 'fee.tradeId = trade.feeTradeId')
    .getMany()
```

```
await getManager().find(Trade, { relations: ['fee'] })
```

My problem: when I use `getManager().find(...)` the `fee` property gets populated with the relation, however, when using the QueryBuilder it is not (`trade.fee` is undefined).

How can I get `fee` populated using a left join with the query builder?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is incorrect:

```
await createQueryBuilder('trade')
.leftJoinAndSelect('trade.fee', 'fee', 'fee.tradeId = trade.feeTradeId')
.getMany()
```

you may get the data without mentioning the condition

```
  await createQueryBuilder('trade')
 .leftJoinAndSelect('trade.fee', 'fee')
 .getMany()
```

here's a doc explaining the syntax: [Explain Typeform join syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66431387/explain-typeorm-join-syntax/66440484#66440484)